# Play 2 JPA Oracle - Extra column 'ebean_intercept' even when ebeanEnabled is set to false in build.scala

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using JPA in Play 2. In my Build.scala, I have the following:

```
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName = "weasel"
  val appVersion = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    javaCore,
    javaJdbc,
    javaJpa,
    "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.1.7.Final"
  )

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    ebeanEnabled := false
  )
}
```

A very simple model:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
@Entity
@Table(name = "event")
public class Event {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "EVENT_NO")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "EVENT_OUTPUT_LOG", length = 250)
    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Standard application.conf config:

```
db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS
jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnit
db.default.logStatements=true
# ebean.default="models.*"
evolutionplugin=disabled
```

When doing a standard select `SELECT e FROM Event e` I see that it is executing the following query:

```
select event0_.EVENT_NO as EVENT1_4_,
event0_._ebean_intercept as column2_4_,
event0_.EVENT_OUTPUT_LOG as EVENT3_4_ 
from EVENT event0_
```

Why is it doing this? I've told it not to use ebeans. I've done a clean compile aswell...but it didn't change anything.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: any luck with this? Iam facing the same problem here with play 2.2..

Comment: No luck unfortunately. We stuck with JPA, but we used Spring DI to manage the persistence. Still using play! framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing `javaEbean` dependency from Build.sbt seems to solve the problem. I dont know why play is using ebean in the first place when ebeanEnabled is set to false.

Comment: That's all that was needed to be done? Ah, thats rather infuriating. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well i had the same problem and i tried removing `javaEbean` but that resulted in the project not compiling.

I removed the ebean enhacement in the build.sbt `ebeanEnabled := false` but that didnt work
I removed the line `ebean.default="models.*` in the application.conf but that didnt work either

Finally i decided to change the name of the package from `models` to `model` and that did it, no more selects and null pointers exceptions from non-existent columns.

Answer (score 0):

Removing javaEbean dependency from Build.sbt as suggested by @armk7 solved my issue, however after removing dependency I was getting ClassNotFounException for Ebean classes. This was because I didn't run activator clean, so few class files were importing ebean files. If you face the same issue do :-
activator clean 
activator reload 
activator compile